# Rocket Chat smtp outgoing email settings with zoho not working

Tags: email, smtp, zoho, rocket.chat

I have a rocket.chat instance running on Google Compute.

I am trying to configure the smtp settings from the Administration menu as specified here -  https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/email/setup/#setup-credentials

I also have my smtp setup with free zoho mails, that works for other services like SendGrid, etc.

So, based on this documentation here - https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/imap-access.html
I initially started with this config -

[image: smtp_config_1]

Then I tested the configuration with all combinations of these values too -

Protocol: smtp, smtps
Port: 465, 587
IgnoreTLS: True, False

But in none of the cases I am receiving any test emails.

Here is my rocket chat log screenshot if that can help debug & solve this issue -

[image]

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Comment: Yes, I know google saves abuse by blocking ports by default. But I added this firewall rule during instance creation - 

alltest (tag)
Apply to all (targets) 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 
all (ports/protocols) 
Allow (action)
1000 (priority) 

& applied the "alltest" tag to the instance. so, I think the problem should not be with port blocking. but if it that problem, how can i debug it to be sure